# Removing the line from top of the table in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am creating website using bootstrap. When I use table the line is displayed only at the top of the table.

I tried to remove the line using the following code:

```
    .table {
  border: 0;
}
```

And the HTML code I used is:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td> ...... </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I remove the line that is displayed above the table?

Comment: Will you create fiddle n share it .. not getting what you want to say 'getting line at top' means ..

Answer (score 1):

You can try out with setting property to important.
If you dont need border to the table:

```
.table{border:none !important;}
```

If you only want to remove top border then:

```
.table{border-top:none !important;}
```

Hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following styles:

```
.table>tbody>tr>td, 
.table>tbody>tr>th, 
.table>tfoot>tr>td, 
.table>tfoot>tr>th, 
.table>thead>tr>td, 
.table>thead>tr>th {
  border:0;
}
```

Comment: He said above, not all.